# System.AddIn, AddInStore.Rebuild causes UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: .net, system.addin, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

my application is loading addins dynamically and when i add
a new module i need to Rebuild the Pipeline segments cache,
but the app doesn't have write permissions in the program folder 
and causes a UnauthorizedAccessException.
i don't want to copy the addins in a temporary directory or the users application directory.

is there a way to find/activate new added addins without rebuilding the pipeline segments cache ?

Comment: Good question. Did you happen to find an anwer on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but maybe with it will works [AddInStore.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470580.aspx)